# NoClassDefFound from Application class

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have been struck on at a point for hours now, i was initializing some code in my Controller.java class that i called from my application class, it was working earlier on all devices but since yesterday i am getting NoClassDefNotFound exception on devices below lolipop..i have not changed anything in this file that may have triggered it

```
 my ApplicationClass code:

 .. onCreate(..){
      ..
      Controller.init(this);
      ..
    }
```

it is imported correctly has no error and it has the following code:

```
  public class Controller {

      ..
      public static final void init(Context context) {
             mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
      }
      ..
  }
```

Package name is correct , i have cleaned,rebuild,invalidated cache and restarted,restarted studios,restated computer.. i have tried everything nothing seems to work.

i am struck for hours now, nothing is working..

code works fine on lollipop (Android 5.0) but crashes below lollipop (Android 5.0)

please help me out

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: post the full stack trace and code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem myself,
android studios has this problem of not showing the exact error when code exceeds 65k methods, like eclipse does with this:

```
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed:
 Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

i had to pull off my hair for 2 days to figure out that NoClassDefFound was being shown to me because i had not enabled multidex.

if you get this problem then write the following code in build.gradle file:

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ..
}
```

if you are targeting Android 5+

for below versions add:

```
 dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 }
```